# Automatic discovery of getters without get prefix

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Is it possible to have jackson automatically discover getters that are not named using the `getFoo()` naming scheme, but instead are just named `foo()`?

Example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

class Test {
    private final String foo;

    public Test(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String foo() {
        return foo;
    }
}

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Test("example")));
    }
}
```

Here, the `foo()` getter is not recognized by jackson. One solution in this case would be to annotate the getter with `@JsonProperty`. However, I'm looking for a way to do this without having to annotate each single getter manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible; the only recognizable aspect here (because 'delve into the bytecode and check if it merely returns a field' is *definitely* not acceptable, as that's internal details that can change in minor updates, and thus, off limits) is 'any method that has no parameters, isn't `static`, and returns something else than `void`).. but other methods might do that too. For example, string's `toLowerCase()`, which certainly isn't a getter in any way or form.

So, even without having any idea of what jackson's capabilities are, what you are asking for is literally completely impossible. It's some pre-established name pattern (such as getX), or an annotation, or an explicit list. No other options.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to override annotation processing as if the assessors without `get` prefix will be considering as annotated as the getters.

```java
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
        PropertyName result = super.findNameForSerialization(a);
        if (result == null) {
            final AnnotatedElement classMember = a.getAnnotated();
            if (classMember instanceof Method) {
                final Method method = (Method) classMember;
                if (method.getParameterCount() == 0 && (method.getModifiers() & (Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.ABSTRACT)) == 0)
                    try {
                        final Field field = method.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredField(method.getName());
                        if (field.getType().equals(method.getReturnType())
                                && (field.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) == 0
                        ) {
                            result = new PropertyName(field.getName());
                        }
                    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                        // ignore
                    }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Cool trick, this - but, think before you leap. This code identifies 'toLowerCase' as a property of java.lang.String. Surely that cannot be the intent. The question as posed (identify 'properties' without annotations and without get prefixes) is just not possible by definition.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, actually this code checks also for field existence, so `toLowerCase` will not treated as property

Comment: but that's also breaking the rules; it is rare but allowed to have a fieldless property. It is _CERTAINLY_ allowed for the field's name to be different from the method name. You're merely creating 'likely, but not guaranteed to work' guesstimates, and that is contrary to everything java is about.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Of course it's better to follow standard JavaBeans convention, but question was about specific conditions.